# How to view on delete / on update constraints?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some tables in a PostgreSQL database, and they have foreign keys with constraints on them (e.g. `add constraint "table_column_fkey" foreign key ("otherTableId") references public."otherTable"(id) on delete cascade on update cascade`).
Some may have `on delete no action`, some `on delete cascade`, others `on delete set null`.

How do I view for a specific constraint what it's `on delete` or `on update` set to?

Comment: Use `\d` in `psql`.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out within the PostgreSQL catalog (eg `information_schema`):

```
SELECT
    constraint_schema,
    constraint_name,
    unique_constraint_name,
    update_rule,
    delete_rule
FROM
    information_schema.referential_constraints rc
```